# VBA : Delete rows using variables

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2007

I wanted to delete rows from 2 to z (z > 2). I wrote 2 methods but neither worked. I searched for answers but didn't find a solution.

```
'.Rows("2:" & z).Select  
.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(z, 10)).Select  
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try .cells as you look to be referencing a sheet?

Comment: If the worksheet you're using `Select` on isn't the `ActiveSheet`, you'll get a run-time error 1004 for 2 reasons: the `Cells` calls aren't qualified, and you can't select cells on the non-active sheet.  Qualify all your references, and use the `Range` objects - not the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify you want to select the rows with `EntireRow`, as your range is only a few cells :

```
.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(z, 10)).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

---

Or cleaner ways if you directly use `Rows` :

```
.Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(z)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Or

```
.Rows("2:" & z).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Wouldn't `.Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(z))` be a bit cleaner?

Comment: @Comintern : It sure would be I wanted to illustrate the use of `EntireRow`, I'll edit to include it ;)

Comment: @FrancisZHENG : Glad I could help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple one line to delete any number of rows you need.

```
Rows("2:" & Z).Delete
```

Comment: Thank you for the help !